# Is there a way to be notified in the fullcalendar vue component when someone switches views?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using the [fullcalendar vue component](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-vue) with the resource-timeline and I can't seem to find a way to be notified when a user switches between views.

I'm sure it's super simple, but the docs are't too great for the vue component.  Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Why do you need to know when the user changes views?

Comment: Anyway if you genuinely do need to know (and there isn't a better way to achieve whatever you're planning to do when that happens) then you can hook into one of the view render callbacks: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks

Comment: @ADyson hi thanks. Yes I tried that but they didn’t seem to get fired when switching between views in the resource timeline. I only really want to know so I can remember for when the user revisits.

Comment: "switching between views in the resource timeline" doesn't make sense. Resource timeline is only one view. So you can't switch between it. Are you talking about when you move to another date range? That's not the same as switching views. Why do you need to remember the user revisiting a certain date range exactly? You could detect the date range change via the event feed callback though if you wanted - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: In my options I’m using the “views” key so I’m sorry that I thought they were views! I’m switching between these errm views? You can see that here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings. So between today/weekly/monthly/four weekly views.

Comment: Ah yes those are different versions of the view. But I think if they are just a different time range, and using the same basic view template, then it won't re-render the view, it's similar to pressing next or previous in that case